# TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000] error

Tags: tikz-pgf, flow-charts

I am trying to make a flowchart. I got an error where it was quite strange to me. What I want is that I need to draw a diamond when I have an "if" condition, but when I change the shape of my "if" condition to a diamond, it throws this error "TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000]". When I change it to a rectangle, it draws it. Any help will be appreciated. Here is my code:

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}[  node distance=2cm,  rect/.style={    draw,    rectangle,    minimum width=3cm,    minimum height=1.5cm,    text centered  },  rectfilled/.style={    rect,    fill=gray!30  },  diamond/.style={    draw,    diamond,    minimum width=1cm,    minimum height=1.5cm, draw=cyan,   text centered  },  arrow/.style={    ->,    very thick,    >=stealth  }]
  \node (start) [rectfilled] {Start};
  \node (input) [rect, below of=start] {Input};
  \node (process1) [rect, below of=input] {Process 1};
  \node (decision) [diamond, below of=process1] {Decision};
  \node (process2a) [rectfilled, below left of=decision, xshift=-4cm] {Process 2a};
  \node (process2b) [rect, below right of=decision, xshift=4cm] {Process 2b};
  \node (output) [rect, below of=process2a] {Output};
  \node (stop) [rectfilled, below of=output] {Stop};
  \draw [arrow] (start) -- (input);
  \draw [arrow] (input) -- (process1);
  \draw [arrow] (process1) -- (decision);
  \draw [arrow] (decision) -- node[anchor=east] {Yes} (process2a);
  \draw [arrow] (decision) -- node[anchor=west] {No} (process2b);
  \draw [arrow] (process2a) -- (output);
  \draw [arrow] (process2b) |- (output);
  \draw [arrow] (output) -- (stop);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`diamond` is a reserved word, already used for the name of a shape in Tikz.

Replace `diamond/.style` by e.g. `diamondstyle/.style`, and use it in `\node (decision)` by replacing `diamond` with `diamondstyle`.

I have also removed in the style for the diamond the first `draw`, as it is superseded by `draw=cyan`.

And I have replaced `anchor=east` and `anchor=west` by `anchor=south` so the texts "Yes" and "No" are not on the line, but slighty above.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance=2cm,  
rect/.style={draw, rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1.5cm, text centered},  
rectfilled/.style={rect, fill=gray!30},
diamondshape/.style={
diamond, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1.5cm, draw=cyan, text centered  
},  
arrow/.style={->, very thick, >=stealth}
]
\node (start) [rectfilled] {Start};
\node (input) [rect, below of=start] {Input};
\node (process1) [rect, below of=input] {Process 1};
\node (decision) [diamondshape, below of=process1] {Decision};
\node (process2a) [rectfilled, below left of=decision, xshift=-4cm] {Process 2a};
\node (process2b) [rect, below right of=decision, xshift=4cm] {Process 2b};
\node (output) [rect, below of=process2a] {Output};
\node (stop) [rectfilled, below of=output] {Stop};
\draw [arrow] (start) -- (input);
\draw [arrow] (input) -- (process1);
\draw [arrow] (process1) -- (decision);
\draw [arrow] (decision) -- node[anchor=south] {Yes} (process2a);
\draw [arrow] (decision) -- node[anchor=south] {No} (process2b);
\draw [arrow] (process2a) -- (output);
\draw [arrow] (process2b) |- (output);
\draw [arrow] (output) -- (stop);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Replacing `diamond` by `shape=diamond` would also solve this problem.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Thanks.

Comment: But you should keep your answer like this, because it indeed tackles the root of the problem, which is having a style inside itself (`diamond/.style={diamond}`) resulting in an endless loop.

Comment: Thanks @quark67 and Jasper Habicht,  it works well now

Comment: @AliSohrabi Feel free to accept the answer (check the mark) if it satisfies your question.